# Turn JavaScript object to ---> JSON ---> mongo ObjectId

Tags: json, mongodb, hash, hex

MongoDb usually stores this information in an ObjectId -

- timestamp
- processid
- machineId
- counter

what I want to do is create a custom 12-byte hash with my own JSON -

say I have JSON like this:

```
{"userId":"<uuid>","ip-address":<whatever>, ....}
```

1. how do I know how much info I can add to the JSON - just number of UTF-8 characters?
2. adding my own custom info is nice of course, but it does need to be unique - besides embedding a uuid in the JSON, what else might I do?
3. NOTE - I want to be able to convert the hash back to a JS object, too, if possible...

Comment: MongoDB uses an ObjectId type for the _id field by default, but that is not required.  You can use whatever data you want in the _id field as long as it is unique

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB stores data in BSON format which supports more types compared with JSON. For example, a timestamp is typically of type `Date`. See the following link for all BSON types: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-types/#bson-types

To answer your questions:

1. Max document size is 16MB -> https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.2/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-BSON-Document-Size
2. Nothing to add. `_id` is always indexed (with the `unique` option) meaning that a new document with the same uuid as a document that's already in the database will not be inserted and instead you'll get an error.